# AdWords PLACEMENT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT not pulling URLs

Tags: google-ads-api

This should be extremely simple but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to pull the URLs of display placements using the DISPLAY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT but instead of URLs it's just returning "--".

The code I'm using is:

```
  var report = AdWordsApp.report(
    "SELECT CampaignName, Clicks, FinalAppUrls, FinalUrls " +
    "FROM   PLACEMENT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT " +
    "WHERE  Clicks > 0 " +   
    "DURING LAST_30_DAYS");

  var rows = report.rows();

  while (rows.hasNext()) {
    var row = rows.next();

    var url = row["FinalUrls"];
    Logger.log(url);

  }
```

I've tried logging the CampaignName and clicks and they're working as expected, so can't understand what the issue is here. The only thing I can think of is that in the reference guide it says:

> List of final URLs of the main object of this row. UrlList elements
>   are returned in JSON list format

I'm not entirely sure what JSON list format is, but when I log the typeof url it says it's a string, so thought it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FinalAppUrls` and `FinalUrls` list the *target URLs* that you set on the individual managed placements.

If you're interested in the URL (domain, rather) of the *placement itself*, you'll have to request either the `Criteria` or the `DisplayName` field in your report——they both contain the domain of the placement.

Comment: Thank you so much! Not sure how I'm supposed to figure these things out, couldn't find any reference to this anywhere!

Comment: Honestly I found out most of what I know about this API by trial and error :D